# Mysqldump not working with cron job using dynamic filename in FreeBSD

Tags: mysql, cron

I want to backup my database automatically using cron job and I want to use dynamic filename indicating the date of backup.

```
* * * * * mysqldump -udbuser -pdbpassword mydb > /backups/mydb.`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`.sql
```

But it seems doesn't work. I check the cron log it shows like this.

```
Oct 31 11:18:00 dbuser /usr/sbin/cron[94330]: (dbuser) CMD (mysqldump -udbuser -pdbpassword mydb > /backups/mydb.`date +")
```

It looks like the command is not executed completely. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cronjobs does not understand those variables.
Below is a php script backup that works for me for many years. It backup as sql and zip it directly.

```
$dbFile = '/data/Backup/backup-'.date('Ymd').'.sql.gz';
$dbHost = 'localhost'; // Database Host
$dbUser = 'username'; // Database Username
$dbPass = 'password'; // Database Password
exec( 'mysqldump --host="'.$dbHost.'" --user="'.$dbUser.'" --password="'.$dbPass.'" --add-drop-table "databasename" | gzip > "'.$dbFile.'"' );
```

and below is the cronjob

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /path_to_backup_script/backup.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not give the extract answer for your question but you can try this:

- Paste this command to bash file (for example: /tmp/backup.sh):

```
 #!/bin/bash
 export TIME=$(date +'%Y%m%d')
 export DATABASEHOST=192.168.100.10
 export SCHEMA="db01 db02"
 export DBPORT="3306"
 export DBPS=$(echo 'password')
 export BACKUPDIR=$(echo '/backup')
 ERR=0
 backup()
 {
 for i in $SCHEMA;
 do
     echo $TIME >> /tmp/db_tar_backup_err.log
     cd $BACKUPDIR
     mysqldump -ubackup -p$DBPS -h $DATABASEHOST -P $DBPORT --single-transaction --routines --triggers $i > db_${i}_$TIME.sql
     tar -czPf db_${i}_$TIME.tar.gz db_${i}_$TIME.sql 2>> /tmp/db_tar_backup_err.log || ERR=1
     find db_${i}_$TIME.sql -delete
 done
 }

 backup()
```

- Create crontab entry:

```
 0 20 * * * /bin/sh /tmp/backup.sh
```

Explain:
 Your script will backup database db01, db02 in order of SCHEMA varibles and using tar to compress it at 20:00